# Java String validation only one alphanumeric with Regex

Tags: java, regex, validation

I want to do validation for a String which can only contains alphanumeric and only one special character. I tried with `(\\W).{1,1}(\\w+)`.

But it is true only when I start with a special character. But I can have one special character at any place in String.

Comment: Please show examples that should be matched and others that shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `^` and `$` anchors to instruct the regex engine to start matching from the beginning of the string and stop matching at the end of the string, so taking your regex:

`^(\\W).{1,1}(\\w+)$`

Please take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) Oracle (Java) tutorial on regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp: `\w*\W?\w*` (Java string: `"\\w*\\W?\\w*"`)

This expression has a drawback of matching zero-length strings. If your input *must* have exactly one special character, remove the question mark `?` from the expression.

Answer (score 0):

use `matcher.find()` and not `matcher.match()` and search for `\\w` and remove plus (+) because it will match all alphanumeric characters sequence in your string.If your string contains only them, your regex will match whole string.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your regex correctly, this could solve your problem:

```
([\w]+)([^\w])([\w]+)
```

Comment: Its simple like i want a string which can alpha numeric and only one special character. eg. valid: abc!   and invalid: abdc@y!